# nested Json file creation using python

Tags: python, json

I want to generate below json file using python.

```
{
    "type": "SubInterface",
    "MTU": 1500,
    "enabled": "True",
    "vlanId": vlanid,
    "subIntfId": subinterid,
    "name": "abc",
    "id": "intid",
    "managementOnly": "False",
    "activeMACAddress":"active-mac",
    "standbyMACAddress":"standby-mac",
    "securityZone": {
      "name": "Zonename",
      "id": "securityid",
      "type": "SecurityZone"
     },
    "ifname": "interface-name",
    "ipv4": {
      "static": {
        "address": ipv4address,
        "netmask": "ipv4subnet"
      }
     },
    "ipv6": {
      "enableIPV6": "True",
      "addresses": [
        {
          "address": ipv6address,
          "prefix": "ipv6prefix",
          "enforceEUI64": "False"
        }
      ]

    }
    }
```

here is my code-

```
import json
data={}

data["type"]="Subinterface"
data["MTU"]="1500"
data["enabled"]= "True"
data["vlanId"]="vlanid"
data["subIntfId"]="subinterid"
data["name"]= "Port-channel24"
data["id"]= "intid"
data["managementOnly"]= "False"
data["activeMACAddress"]="active-mac"
data["standbyMACAddress"]="standby-mac"
data['securityZone']=[]
data['securityZone'].append({
      "name": "Zonename",
      "id": "securityid",
      "type": "SecurityZone"
    })
data["ifname"]="interface-name"
data['ipv4']=[]
data['ipv4'].append({
data["static"]=[]
data["static"].append({
             "address": "ipv4address",
             "netmask": "ipv4subnet"
             })
     })

with open('data1.txt', 'w') as outfile:
   json.dump(data, outfile)
```

while executing it gives me below error -

```
automation) -bash-4.1$ python json23.py
  File "json23.py", line 23
    data["static"]=[]
                  ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

How to generate json with nested values

Comment: `ipv4` and `static` are not lists according to your spec.

Answer (score 0):

It is because you have unclosed brackets on the previous line: `data['ipv4'].append({`. If you close up those brackets you should be all good.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with this block:

```
data['ipv4']=[]
data['ipv4'].append({
data["static"]=[]
data["static"].append({
             "address": "ipv4address",
             "netmask": "ipv4subnet"
             })
     })
```

As a commented pointed out, your desired output does not have lists for `ipv4` and `static`. I suspect you want it to read:

```
data['ipv4'] = {
    "static": {
        "address": "ipv4address",
        "netmask": "ipv4subnet"
    }
}
```

Or if you insist on square bracket notation (though I'm not sure why you would):

```
data['ipv4'] = {}
data['ipv4']['static'] = {}
data['ipv4']['static']['address'] = 'ipv4address'
data['ipv4']['static']['netmask'] = 'ipv4subnet'
```

Some other notes:

1. You don't need to initialise an empty list and then `append` to it - you can just initialise the list with the values that you want.
2. I'd suggest that initialising this `dict` directly, instead of dynamically building it like here, is preferable where possible.